# PHP email failing to send with specific formatting character

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send an auto response email using PHP.

Here is the code for the body

```
$body = "<html><body>";
$body .= "Dear " . $_POST['contactName'].",";
$body .= "<br><br>";
$body .= "Welcome to......";
$body .= "<br><br>";
$body .= "Thank you for your application.";
$body .= "<br><br>";
$body .= "In order to further process your application could you please provide us <br>";
$body .= "with electronic copies of the following documents regarding your company:";
$body .= "<br><br>";
$body .= "- VAT Certificate";
$body .= "<br>";
$body .= "- Certificate of Incorporation";
$body .= "<br>";
$body .= "- Company Intro Letter";
$body .= "<br>";
$body .= "- Director's Passport";
$body .= "<br>";
$body .= "- Utility Bill of the Company and the Director";
$body .= "<br><br>";
$body .= "Please send electronic copies by email to: dinoangelides@gmail.com/";
$body .= "Once we have received these documents we will process your application.";
$body .= "<br><br>";
$body .= "If successful we will provide you with your secure login details,";
$body .= "<br>";
$body .= "which will allow you to access the website.";
$body .= "<br><br>";
$body .= "Please do not hesitate to contact us for any additional information required.";
$body .= "<br><br>";
$body .= "Best regards,";
$body .= "<br><br>";
$body .= '<img src="some link" width="202" height="59"/>';
$body .= "<br><br>";
$body .= "Support Team";
$body .= "<br>";
$body .= "IPVDX | B2B Experts";
$body .= "</body></html>";
```

now php send the email just fine but on this line

```
$body .= "Please send electronic copies by email to: dinoangelides@gmail.com/";
```

If i remove the / the email does not go....
and it does not let me put a break line below it to separate the two lines, therefore the message is connected at that point with the line below

any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Do you get some error message?

Comment: the email does not go.... what error message are you getting?

Comment: the rest of the code you use to send the mail could be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried line break "\n" ?

Comment: use single quote in that line instead of double quote :-) and <br> at the end